# Is this php loop correct, my lightbox displays wrong images

Tags: php, jquery, loops, lightbox

I am using the fancybox lightbox and want to quickly add pictures to my page so I am trying this PHP code, however when I click on an image the wrong one is displayed. The thumbnail and large image are both the same digit in separate folders.

```
                <?php

                $initialImageNumber = 1;
                $endingImageNumber  = 38;

                $title = "click to enlarge";


                for ($i = $initialImageNumber; $i <= $endingImageNumber; $i++)

                    echo '<a href="images/barpics/' . $i . '.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" title="' . $title .'"><img src="images/thumb/'. $i .'.jpg" /></a>';

                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well This code is somewhat ok, tho you can simplify this code a bit more

```
<?php
$totalImages  = 38;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalImages; $i++) {
   echo '<a href="images/barpics/' . $i . '.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" title="click to enlarge"><img src="images/thumb/'. $i .'.jpg" /></a>';
}
?>
```

or just use for loop. Regarding the images, my guess is that images don't match. Load the web page with this script, open it's source, check the ID of the image. Then go to the images folder `images/barpics/` and `images/thumb/` and view the image with that specific ID.
My guess is that they don't match and that's causing the problem with it.

Comment: I tried your code which works, and checked the file paths and they don't match up which is why it's displaying the wrong images. However on my local directory they are the same file names, I'm not sure why they change when I run the localhost or on my server

Comment: First check if all images are same type, in this case .jpg
After that check if `images/barpics/15.jpg` is the same as `images/thimb/15.jpg` (open them with some image viewing program).

I'd suggest you to go from 1-38, open each image (with image viewing program) from both folders, compare them and see if thumb is equal to the barpics image.

Comment: For now I've found a way to work around this, I'm using the same image and styling the thumbnail image using inline code width & height. Not the best way, and It'll take longer to load but I will come back to it soon. Thanks for the help

Comment: Well that's not the best practice. I'd suggest you to make new thumbnails. Clear the current thumbnails folder, open each image from folder barpics, resize it to the size that you want and save it in thumb folder with same name. After that use the script from above to load it. Problem solved :)

Comment: Also if you want to stick with your plan of using width and height image properties for making thumbnails, I've edited the above php code for you.

http://codepad.org/7Tl0sJDK

Just change xxx in width and height sizes :)
Cheers